# In TodoApp, on click of item in TodoList call function from TodoApp

Tags: reactjs

I was learning some react. I started with the TodoApp. TodoApp calls the component TodoList. Now on each item, when a user clicks it, I want it to trigger the function of TodoApp.rmItem(i, e) so I tried this:

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
    createItem: function(itemText, index) {
      return <li key={index + itemText} onClick={this.context.rmItem.bind(null, index)}>{itemText}</li>; ////////////// ISSUE
    },
  render: function() {
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(this.createItem)}</ul>;
  }
});

var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: [], text: ''};
  },
  onChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.state.items.push(this.state.text);
    this.state.text = '';
    this.forceUpdate();
  },
  rmItem: function(i, e) {
    console.log('e:', e);
    alert(this.state.items[i]);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>TODO</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.text} />
          <button>{'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1)}</button>
        </form> 
        <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, mountNode);
```

The issue is the commented line:

```
 onClick={this.context.rmItem.bind(null, index)}
```

How can I tap into the parent scope, and give it arguments?

This example doesnt stand: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

The only solution i was thinking of was setting the scope in here:

```
<TodoList items={this.state.items} />
```

adding to it, this:

```
<TodoList items={this.state.items} parentScope={this} />
```

Thanks

Comment: You could pass an onClick from TodoApp, through TodoList and finally to TodoItem?

Comment: Thanks @DominicTobias can you please show in some code :( English not my first language :(